# Changing a user session to a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I'm building an app which has users, pages and groups.  I want users to be able to message the pages, and for the admins of pages to be able to reply as the page, as is done on Facebook.  I'm not really sure how to go about this in Rails though.  Does anybody know how this is done on Facebook?  Would the user session be destroyed and another session created for the page, through an admin column?  That's the only way I can think of it being done, but am not sure how to go about this using Devise.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of "context switching" method. i.e: I'm logged in as a user, but I can switch my context to a page if I'm one of the page admins. Switching contexts can be handled using namespaces.

You may also check mailboxer gem, it allows objects to message each other. i.e: a user can message a page and you can set it up so page admins are notified if there's a new message. If you're a page admin, you can switch your context to a page and reply to the message, and so on.

Comment: Can't find much online about context switching, but that sounds like what I was talking about.  Is that ver different to changing a session then?  I have looked into Mailboxer, but there are then issues of user interface with those messages from different pages, etc.